# How map <leader>char in Vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, remap

I just installed [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides) plugin.

The default mapping to toggle the plugin is `<Leader>ig` and I want to remap this to Ctrl-i.

These are my attempts:

```
nnoremap <C-i> <leader>ig
nnoremap <C-i> <Leader>ig
```

I have a similar approach to switch to relative numbers with Ctrl-n and it's working:

```
nnoremap <C-n> :set relativenumber!<ENTER>
```

What's wrong with the `<Leader>` key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `:noremap`, the original mapping isn't considered. Though `:noremap` is usually preferred to avoid interactions with other mappings, here you do need to allow remapping:

```
nmap <C-i> <leader>ig
```

This plugin offers a `<Plug>` mapping to facilitate remapping; then, the original `<Leader>ig` isn't even defined and free for other uses! Therefore, unless you want to have *both*, prefer this:

```
nmap <C-i> <Plug>IndentGuidesToggle
```

Note: This is all documented by the plugin under `:help indent-guides-mappings`.